# How to delete outliers after plotting a boxplot with Seaborn?

Tags: pandas, statistics, seaborn, boxplot, outliers

I am trying to delete the outliers from my dataset.

Here are the boxplots: [image: boxplots]

How can I get the value of the end of the whisker?

Let's say:
min has the value: 0
my 25th quartile has the value: 125
my 75th quartile has the value: 1938
max has the value: 113499

I tried something like the following, but not sure if it's right:

```
clean_model.drop(clean_model[clean_model.num_likes > (1938 + (1.5* (1938-125)))].index, inplace=True)
```

Is that calculation (1938 + (1.5* (1938-125))) right, to get the value of the point in the plot?

Below is the description of my dataframe:

[image: describe dataframe]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're calculation is correct. The whisker length is calculated as some 'whisker' factor (default is 1.5 in matplotlib / seaborn) multipled by the inter-quartile range (iqr).

Using `numpy.percentile` for example:

```
import numpy as np

p_25, p_75 = np.percentile(clean_model['num_likes'], [25, 75])
iqr = p_75 - p_25

upper_bound = p_75 + 1.5 * iqr
lower_bound  = p_25 - 1.5 * iqr
```

`scipy.stats` also has a convenience function `iqr` you could use:

```
from scipy.stats import iqr

_iqr = iqr(clean_model['num_likes'])
```

Comment: Thank you! (maybe out of subject, but you could perhaps help here) Is it normal, than when I clean the outliers from my dataset, the accuracy and f1-scores drop by approximately 5%?  RandomForestClassifier in a Binary Classification problem

Comment: It's difficult to say without a bit more context... I would pose the question on the stack exchange data science community. https://datascience.stackexchange.com/ Give some details such as what are you predicting? What model or algorithm are you using, what hyper parameters, how are other evaluation metrics or your confusion matrix impacted etc

Comment: Okay. Thank you for you time!